# why is it giving error

Tags: tikz-cd

(Error)

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
M \arrow{r}{i} \arrow{d}
  & A3  \\
    & A2
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

(Non Error)

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
M \arrow{r}{i} 
  & A3 \arrow{d}{h} \\
    & A2
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which error? Please add the complete message to your question ... And please make the code snippets compilable ...

Comment: Better using `\arrow[r,"i"]` for the horizontal arrow and `\arrow[d]` for the vertical one.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `\arrow` can be simplified, now that PGF version 3 is available.

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
M \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[d] & A3  \\
  & A2
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

All options are specified in a single place; the label is given in double quotes.

The “old” form can still be used, but for the vertical unlabeled arrow it requires an empty argument: `\arrow{d}{}`.